# Python: can't open file [Errno 2]

Tags: python

Using the gedit editor I have made a file ex1.py. My system is Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have tried many solutions including giving the full path like
python /home/xyzpc/mystuff/learnpython/ex1.py. For understanding purpose mystuff and learnpython are the two folders I have created and inside learnpython I have kept the ex1.py file. BUT again it is showing 
python: can't open file 'ex1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Please help. I know it is a duplicate one but unable to fix the issue

Comment: What does the command `ls -l $HOME/mystuff/learnpython/` say?

Comment: My input as per your instruction was xyzpc:$ ls -l $home/mystuff/learnpython/. When I entered this it gave me ls: cannot access '/mystuff/learnpython/': No such file or directory. No way out, please help

Comment: @ShirshenduDe Linux is case sensitive - `$home` is not the same thing as `$HOME`

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, one more addition to my knowledge. This input as directed gave output as -  total 12 (first line) -rwxrwxr- x 1 username username 216 Aug 1 14:20 ex1 (second line)

Comment: So as you can see, you didn't make a file `ex1.py` - you made a file `ex1`

Comment: But I saved the file in the folder giving file type as Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and type `python`  (python followed by a space), then drag the ex1.py file into the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If the command executes successfully you now know two things.

1. ex1.py executed successfully.
2. When you drag a file from the file manager into the terminal it automatically prints the complete path to that file. In order to access ex1.py using `cd` change directories to the directory that contains ex1.py which can be identified from the path to ex1.py.

Comment: Thanks @karel, it worked greatly. Thanks again as this added to my knowledge that as to what happens when we drag a file from a file folder to a terminal.

Comment: For future users of this thread. When I dragged the file into the terminal automatically it took the path and executed what I had written in the gedit text editor and the same which I saved with the extension .py. When I pressed enter it gave the results and the the first line appeared as python 'home/username/mystuff/learnpython/ex1'. Now again to try in a different way I tried using the same line without the quotation marks at the start and at the end. Again it worked. Now the mistake which I was doing was to put .py after ex1.  Write only ex1. This solves the issue